# How to restrict user to create a folder inside blob container in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I have created blob container to upload files from user side, I need to restrict user to create any other folder inside that container.

I have tried creating access policy and all, nothing help on this.

Comment: there is no actual folder inside blob container. The folder is actual part of the blob name.

Comment: need to restrict user further to create any subfolders inside it.

Comment: You can add role assignment as a reader only to a particular user in Azure

Comment: @shivakumar, regarding "upload files from user side", does it mean the user upload the files via code or some tools?

Comment: @ivanYang , using via code

Comment: @shivakumar, if the user can write code via blob storage sdk to upload files, then they can define the blob name as they like, eg. "aa/bb/test.txt", then it will create folder aa and bb inside blob container. If possible, you provide them a UI tool, then you can control the blob name with your own logic.